# Copying Formulas to cell range - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to using VBA's. I created a few simple successful codes, however I have created this and somehow it does not work every time I run them.

I will appreciate if someone can correct it or simplify the 3 codes together so it will run simultaneously.

Thanks for the help.

```vb
'for copying formulas in Cell M1

Sub formulaMain()

    Dim f As String
    f = Range("M1").FormulaR1C1
    
    Range("M2:M1280").FormulaR1C1 = f
    
        Next
    Call formulaMain2
    Call CopyAndPasteValues
    
End Sub
______________________________________________________________________
'for copying formulas in Cell N1

Sub formulaMain2()

    Dim f As String
    f = Range("N1").FormulaR1C1
    
    Range("N2:N1280").FormulaR1C1 = f
    
End Sub
____________________________________________________________________

'for copy_Paste special Values of Column L

Sub CopyAndPasteValues()
  
    ActiveSheet.Range("N2:N1280").Select
    Selection.Copy 
    Range("L2:L1280").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: What does “does not work” mean?

Comment: it prompts this message. "Comple error: Next without For"... I think I messed up when I add the Next in Sub formulamain()... I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: That is not an error that would be intermittent.

Comment: Remove the Next in the first block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
Sub AllInOne()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("M1:N1").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("M1:N1280"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        .Range("L2:L1280").Value = .Range("N2:N1280").Value
    End With
End Sub
```